# Duplicate error in Attribute XML

Tags: android, xml

I have been working on this XML code and got error stating duplicate error attribute I went through the code but couldn't find the solution.

Here is my XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="WIMBELDON FINALS"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.vidit.project2.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="roger federer"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="scorer"
                android:text="POINT" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Sets Won: "
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/setr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.vidit.project2.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="djokovic"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="POINT" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Sets Won: "
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/setd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="RESET" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error being Showed :Error parsing XMl duplicate Attribute.

Please Guide me.

Thank you

Comment: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head I see "xmlns:android" appearing twice in your root RelativeLayout; try removing one of those and seeing if that does the trick!